# TensorFlow 2.9.1 model.predict error when using array of Tensors as input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

From according to [Keras Sequential Model.predict()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict) documentation, the model can use a variety of input forms, including:

> A TensorFlow tensor, or a list of tensors (in case the model has multiple inputs).

I want to test model by using image sets from **image_dataset_from_directory**.

[Test dataset_Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euspg.jpg)

However I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Layer "model" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 224, 224, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>]
```

The shapes are as follows:

- **image_batch** `<KerasTensor: shape=(7, 224, 224, 3) dtype=float32`
- **label_batch** `tf.Tensor([0 0 1 1 2 2 2], shape=(7,), dtype=int32)`

How can I solve this ValueError ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do this

```
preds=new_model.predict(Test_dataset)
for i, p in enumerate(preds):
    file=os.path.basename(Test_dataset.filenames[i])
    index=np.argmax(p)
    pred_klass=class_names[index]
    print(f'{file:^30s}{pred_class:^6s}')
```

this will predict all the test files

Comment: Thank you. But I got the ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2). And I solve the error by createa list for kept the value in preds.

Comment: oups i forgot to enumerate preds see modified answer